# Install VBOX guest additions on Debian Testing

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Is there a way to install the Virtualbox's guest additions on Debian Testing ? When I try the 'classic way', I get this message :

> Building the main Guest Additions module ...fail!
>   (Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)

**/var/log/vboxadd-install.log :**

> /tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:97: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR= and run Make again. Stop.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: I just edited the post.

Comment: Maby this can help? http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-virtualbox-on-centos-redhat-and-fedora/
See the part about "export KERN_DIR".

Answer (score 1):

you need to have the kernel-headers installed, e.g.

```
$ sudo aptitude install linux-headers-amd64
```

this will install the *default* linux-headers, if you have a non-default kernel, you need to install the matching headers.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get them installed by the following.

```
apt-get install dkms build essential
```

then with "Guest Additions CD image" inserted.

```
sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Reboot and guest additions worked fine.

Comment: Same for me: This are complete instructions that worked for me: https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-debian-step-by-step

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything possible to use guest additions when using ubuntu as guest and never got it working. As soon as I installed ubuntu, guest additions installed without a hitch

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following command.

```
sudo yum install kernel-devel    
sudo yum upgrade
```

and then restart you virtual machine.
This methods works for me best.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install kernel packages like other said.

If you use a graphical destop.You must switch to root user to run VBoxLinuxAdditions.run.

It's worked on centos7 with virtualbox5.1.28.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I use to install the guest additions:

`sudo bash
apt-get install build-essential module-assistant
module-assistant prepare`

*<change directory to wherever you have the Guest Additions CD mounted>*

`sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

It's probably best to reboot after installing the guest additions, so the modules can load themselves properly.

This should work on any Debian-based distro.  I know it works on at least Debian (Wheezy -> Stretch, and possibly back to Sarge) and Ubuntu 10.04 -> 17.10.